# Seal on a painting

Tags: old-chinese

[image]

Can anyone translate what is written here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: seems like 半夏山人

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

looks like "半岛山人", aka "wildman on a peninsula", to me.

The different ancient form of 岛：
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !